# communicate with other running application methods in android

Tags: android, media-player, sensors

I want to create an application similar to Air Gesture Control. How do I get the current running song and work on the running media player application. Let me give a better explanation.

I started **walkman / any media player** application, minimize it. Now I started my application, implemented the `SensorEventListener` for Proximity Sensor after registering it.

Now I want to know how can I call the `play / pause / next / previous` methods of the **walkman / media player** currently running.

Please give me at least few **terms / links** where I can find some information about it.

Thanks in Advance.

Sorry for not giving any code :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800198/control-the-default-music-player-of-android-or-any-other-music-player

Comment: If that solution is not robust enough (ie doesn't work on certain music players that Air Gesture Control does) you could decompile Air Gesture Control and see what intents they send. Make sure to cleanroom reverse engineer it before incorporating it in your own app, of course.

Comment: What if I am not thinking just only to control the behavior of music player. I can select any application and use there method in mine based on SensorEventListener.

Comment: I tested the code on link stackoverflow.com/questions/18800198/, it is only selecting the default music player. I have installed two or more music player in my phone. But AudioManager is always selecting my default music player and not the other installed music player. Please help. More over play / pause is not working. I can pause the song but can't able to play the song.

Comment: And That Air Gesture also not able to do the same... It works with walkman(Sony), but not with Google Play Music on the same phone.