# How to control currently playing music player in android?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I use this code to send actions like play/pause for music player.

```
// play / pause
i.putExtra("command", "togglepause");
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

But it works only for default music player (phone's own music player). Is there any way to control other music players while they're playing?

Comment: Broadcast intents don't work properly as well as support Spotify. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800198/control-the-default-music-player-of-android-or-any-other-music-player/53961746#53961746) with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this -

```
 i.putExtra("command", "pause");
```

EDIT:

Alternate Solution, List programmatically all music apps using PackageManager , Intent, ResolveInfo etc. and than send command to all apps in the list.

Comment: Yeah! But it's not the point. play, pause, stop, next, previous all of these works only for default music player in this way. I want to send these commands somehow that also works for other music players.

Comment: hmmm.. than you need to list programmatically all music apps using PackageManager , Intent, ResolveInfo etc. and than send command to all apps in the list.

Have you tried this?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Novarg UpVote received Comment can be considered as solution to the original problem.

Comment: @KanakSony Am I able to find out which one is currently playing after that I got the list of all installed music players. Because I want to send these commands only to the one that is currently playing, not all of them.

Answer (score 4):

From API level 19, new API `dispatchMediaKeyEvent()` is introduced.

> Sends a simulated key event for a media button. To simulate a key press, you must first send a KeyEvent built with a ACTION_DOWN action, then another event with the ACTION_UP action.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    downEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE);
    am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(downEvent);

    upEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE);         
    am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(upEvent);
```

This media event will be dispatched to the current running music player only, not to all players.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I was working on an app that controls the headset buttons(including media button). and for events on that my app is the one that gets the events not players. So this method won't work for my case. But thanks anyway.