# How to pause media player when skype call comes

Tags: android, skype, android-music-player

I've developed a music player app where i need to pause music when user gets a call through his skype app. I've tried AudioFocus and phone state listener concepts but it is not working for skype. Can somebody help me out on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you getting the skype call state? Did you make a service or BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @Tushar, i'm not able get skype call state, is there any way that i can get skype call state? I've implemented AudioFocus in my app it works fine, but not for Skype. So i would like to know is there any particular way that i can detect skype call state? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800198/control-the-default-music-player-of-android-or-any-other-music-player . You should catch incoming "stop" intent and react.

Answer (score 0):

This link show you how it done with phone call. Sometimes it will help you.

[Stopping & Starting music on incoming calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610464/stopping-starting-music-on-incoming-calls)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, The above method works fine when user gets Incoming phone calls, but not skype calls, I would like to know is there a way that we can detect skype call state? thanks in advance.