# Xamarin Form and android: How to remotely to play/pause/stop a media player on another device

Tags: android, video, media-player, remote-control

I have two devices. One to play the video and the other device will be used as a remote. Later device had a network connection using Thrift to communicate with former device.

How can I control the former device to play/stop/pause through the later device. The communication from later device to former device is ok. But the message get to former device, how do I play/stop etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from other post.

[Control the default music player of android or any other music player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800198/control-the-default-music-player-of-android-or-any-other-music-player)

but can we retrieve the status of the media player with intent.