# How to send media action button to current player?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, mediacontroller

Is there any way to send a media action button to current media player (like Walkman or google play music) to play and pause or next and previous song.

actually i want to create a simple remote control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800198/control-the-default-music-player-of-android-or-any-other-music-player)

```
if (mAudioManager == null) mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY);
mAudioManager.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(event);
```