# getting "undefined is not a function" when trying to add an new function to existing react native library

Tags: android, react-native

Im trying to add an new function to an existing react native library called [react-native-system-setting](https://github.com/c19354837/react-native-system-setting), for my application i need to be able to simulate key events for playing, pausing and skipping songs on different media players as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800198/control-the-default-music-player-of-android-or-any-other-music-player) so i added the function  "MediaControl" to the [react-native-system-setting](https://github.com/c19354837/react-native-system-setting) library:

```
public SystemSetting(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    mContext = reactContext;
    reactContext.addLifecycleEventListener(this);
    am = (AudioManager) mContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    wm = (WifiManager) mContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    lm = (LocationManager) mContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    listenVolume(reactContext);
}

@ReactMethod
public void MediaControl(String Command ) {
long eventtime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    switch (Command) {
        case "next":
            KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT, 0);
            am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(downEvent);

            KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT, 0);
            am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(upEvent);

        case "previous":
            KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS, 0);
            am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(downEvent);

            KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS, 0);
            am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(upEvent);

        case "play":
            KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0);
            am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(downEvent);

        case "pause":
            KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE, 0);
            am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(upEvent);
    }
}
```

it builds ok on android studio, but when i try to use the function i get an error:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating '_reactNativeSystemSetting2.default.MediaControl("play")')
```

am i missing something?

Comment: Did you add your module to your ReactPackage?  Do you have a custom ReactPackage?

Comment: Also, you aren't passing in a Promise to the function.  It may be possible to do it without it, but generally every ReactMethod's last parameter is a Promise that you resolve or reject when appropriate.

Comment: It was a silly mistake, i forgot to declare the function on the javascript side of things, at node_modules\react-native-system-setting\SystemSetting.js